# How to make a php curl / POST processing url?

Tags: php, curl

What I'm trying to ask is a url on which any one can POST variables on to it. How can I create a PHP page which can accept variables sent via post, sent either through curl or by form post or whatever.

Can I just accept variables sent via post just by using

```
$_POST['varible']
```

so that If someone post a 'variable' to my url,will I be able to get it

Comment: that's how it works. just set up a simple php test file with a form and you can test sending variables over GET/POST

Comment: if the client uses curl to post,will this solution works?

Comment: If client's use curl, they have to specify the curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $poststring);

Comment: At my end,I just have to use $_POST[''] to accept those variables even if client uses curl or any POST methods right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can accept the value using $_POST.form datas which are posted to a php is recieved using what you said

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { //Check if the submit button is pressed.
    $field1 = $_POST['field1']; //Take the post data of "field1" from the form.
    $field2 = $_POST['field2']; //Take the post data of "field2" from the form.
    echo "$field1 $field2"; //Echo the fields.
}
?>
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="field1" placeholder="Field 1"><br>
<input type="text" name="field2" placeholder="Field 2"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Data">
</form>
```

Comment: I just not only asking about the form.What if if curl is used.How will I get the values?Is it the same as how we do for form?